# BR / EDR / LE Android Kitkat combo issue

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-peripheral

I'm trying to send 2 chunks of 20 bytes in **BLE** from Central to peripheral.
Its all fine.

after that i want to send a image using classic socket connection.

Image is transferred in **Lollipop** but not in **kitkat** or **jelly bean**.

Can somebody help me with this. I get socket timeout exception always.

> **Note:**
>
> Only sending image using classic socket code in **kitkat** or **jelly bean**
>   works without doing BLE data transfer